# Django - Calling self save in a model method

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wonder if I change the model from inside a model method I shoudl call `save()` and if so how?

Example model:

```
class Case(Model):

    some_number = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)


    def add(self, amount):
        self.some_number += amount
        self.save(update_fields=['some_number']) # needed?
```

Called like this:

```
case = Case(some_number)
case.add(10)
```

Is this needed? correct? I'll be glad for advice about that

Comment: There's no correct approach to this. It very much depends on how you use your models. You should save the updated field within the model method if you cannot expect the caller to save the entire instance at a later point, but even this advice is not applicable to every scenario out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you mean about "needed" or "correct". It's needed and correct if you want to persist the change immediately on calling `add`, and clearly document that this is the method's behaviour.